# CppUTest and CppUTestExt libraries in cpputest

Tags: unit-testing, scons, cpputest

I am using cpputest library to test my application. I am using scons.
when I call SConScriptUtest, I get the following error:

> cannot find -lCppUTest
>   cannot find -lCppUTestExt

This is while I have included the path for finding CppUTest and CppUTestExt:

> LIBPATH points to where your libraries reside:   testenv.Append(LIBPATH = ['../cpputest/lib'])

my ../cpputest/lib path has both CppUTest.lib and CppUTestExt.lib

So why is it not picking up?

Comment: Are you using the testenv environment to build your test program?  testenv.Program(...)  If that's not it, can you post the full build command scons generates and the full resulting error?

Comment: @KennethE.Bellock I have my scons code added above.

Comment: SConscript is helpful, but even more so if you can scale it down to a minimal example.  Can you post the build line scons generates to make your test executable, and the full resulting error?

Comment: @KennethE.Bellock the problem is building for platform. I was building for posix whereas it's gotta be building for win32 platfrom, thanks for your help anyways.